# Will Apple reject my app if I do not do this?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

From the documentation of UITableView / UITableViewController:

> If you decide to use a
> UIViewController subclass rather than
> a subclass of UITableViewController to
> manage a table view, you should
> perform a couple of the tasks
> mentioned above to conform to the
> human-interface guidelines.
>
> To clear
> any selection in the table view before
> it’s displayed, implement the
> viewWillAppear: method to clear the
> selected row (if any) by calling
> deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:.
> After the table view has been
> displayed, you should flash the scroll
> view’s scroll indicators by sending a
> flashScrollIndicators message to the
> table view; you can do this in an
> override of the viewDidAppear: method
> of UIViewController.

So lets say I do my custom stuff here and I do not flash the scroll indicator, and I do not reset the selection (which I think is wrong anyways, the user wants to know from where he came from). Will they reject it?

Comment: This is probably a valid question, but the fact that Apple has made developers ask questions like this is *scary*.

Comment: The whole idea of "apple must approve" is so sad..

Comment: Imagine if computer software developers would have to go through all this... *shudder*

Comment: But it leads to consistent applications which behaves in the way the users knows and expects :)

Comment: Why should a 3rd party have any control over what *my* app does?

Comment: @Felix there's a point to that but at too high a cost IMO. A single company controlling the entire distribution channel, being able to reject apps at a whim, is something I would never want to participate in. I also predict it is going to fail as DRM did. My next laptop will be a MacBook but I will never buy an iPhone/iPad as long as the only way to get apps on it is through the Apple store.

Comment: @Matti the problem starts when a virus programmer says exactly that :)

Comment: @Pekka: Well I can understand the concerns against this, I have them too, most annoying that I can't just develop my own app for my own iPhone (I don't have one, just theoretically). But I can also understand Apple. They want *ensure* the working of the iPhones. It is a trade off and everyone has to decide whether he takes it or not.

Comment: Pekka: I don't quite think having "bad user experience" is comparable to viruses.

Comment: @Matti yeah, I was exaggerating. I'm not against platforms with stringent UX rules, though - I would be happy to see an Open Source platform that imposes such rules, thus providing a more consistent experience to end users (which is why people buy Apple). I don't like it, though, when this is dictated for an entire platform. @Felix yup, it's down to choice in the end. But I really predict it's going to take the way of AOL - they, too, tried to moderate the content their users got to see (and charge extra for the moderation). They were defeated by the free Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple *may* reject it.  In practice, they won't (this is practical experience, not inside knowledge).  They will reject apps now for using their private api, although in the past they wouldn't.  But if your app sucks, not flashing scroll indicators might be a reason they give for rejecting it.  If not deselecting a cell is important to your UX, then you should be ok - or it's possible that you have a poor UX.

Deselecting the cell should be animated - so the user gets the hint of where they came back from, which they should be able to remember anyway.  But retaining the selection could lead the user to think that the selection is somehow significant and will affect their subsequent actions, which from your description it won't.  So lose the selection.