# Cancel button on UIActionSheet on iPad

Tags: ipad, uiactionsheet

The iOS Human Interface Guide says that on an iPad "Do not include a Cancel button when the action sheet is displayed without animation, because people can tap outside the popover to dismiss the action sheet without selecting one of the other alternatives". As a result, the Cancel button is not shown in these cases.

This is NOT intuitive. People are used to seeing a Cancel option whenever an action that can be cancelled is shown, and they may get confused if they don't see one. They may not realize that tapping outside the popver means Cancel.

The reasoning of "clicking outside the window to cancel" could have been used for PCs and Macs as well, but it isn't. A Cancel button is displayed in these systems.

I'm inclined to include an artificial Cancel button, but I'm afraid that this is against Apple HIG policy and my App will be rejected.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who just encountered the same issue, I agree. It's not intuitive whatsoever!

As for [Apple's recommendations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf)

- "Do not include a Cancel button when the action sheet is displayed without animation, because people can tap outside the popover to dismiss the action sheet without selecting one of the other alternatives." (p121)
- "An animated action sheet should include a Cancel button, because people need to be able to dismiss the action sheet without closing the popover" (p121)

Will Apple reject your app if you don't follow these guidelines? This answer may offer some insight:

[Will Apple reject my app if I do not do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613099/will-apple-reject-my-app-if-i-do-not-do-this)